# How to increment variable when term is completed

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Input places in km, people can stay in place if it's away from them less than 150 km from current place. First current place is 0.

**Input:**

```
100 120 200 300 420 500 580 645 740 870 980 1100 1230 1300 1377
```

**Output:**

```
2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 13.
```

1. First thing i did was current place+150=150
2. Then numbers who are less than that: 100 and 120
3. Then highest number is: 120
4. Highest number=current place
5. To compare next: currentplace+150 and so on.

```
    int less[15]={},array[15]={100, 120, 200, 300, 420, 500, 580, 645, 740, 870, 980, 1100, 1230, 1300, 1377}, i,j, current[15]={0},tmp, compare[15]={0}, bigger[15]={0};

    printf("People will stay at: \n");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        current[i]=150+array[i];

        if(array[i]<current[i])
        {
            less[i]=array[i];
            printf("Less are:%d\n", less[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("Max number of less number I found previousli is: ");
    for(i=1;i<15;i++)
    {
      int max=less[0];
      if(less[i]>max)
      {
        max=less[i];

        printf("\Biggerje: %d, they will stay at %d\n", max,i+1);
      }
    }
```

I dont know how to find max number from less[i] numbers and add it to current position within for loop

Comment: If you do `current[i]=150+array[i]` then immediately after `array[i]<current[i]` will *always* be true.

Comment: I wanted to save max number of less numbers: 100 and 200 as array[i]

Comment: I dont know how to increment current position properly

Comment: I think that this problema has an easy solution but... I honestly don't understand what would be the expected result. The next place must be the farest place in the array within 150km? Could you please write the expected current place sequence?

Comment: And what do you mean with *when term is complited*?

Comment: 1.)Input: :100 120 200 300 420 500 580 645 740 870 980 1100 1230 1300 1377
Current place=0;
numbers<150 are 100 and 120  (120 is max)
current place is max+150=270

2.)same pattern
Current place=270;
numbers<270 are 100 and 120 and 200 (200 is max)
current place is max+150=470

Comment: @Equus please [edit] your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: Edit the question with the expected output, so that anyone can help you with the loop you are looking for.

Comment: You say you can't find the `max` but you have the confused `max=less[i]; max=array[i];` . Did you intend `less[i]=max;`? Note that in the earlier `less[i]=array[i];` not all elements of `less[]` are written to: the others are *uninitialised*.

Comment: I wanted to increment curren position with numbers from array but it wasnt so good

Comment: yes that was my intend Weather less[i]=max;

Comment: Can you please [improve the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58818550/how-to-increment-varijable-when-term-is-complited#comment103915080_58818550), and ask a specific question? Your last but one comment adds nothing meaningful. What is "it"? *which* array?